# Apache2: 2 virtual hosts (domain & subdomain) / 1 IP - not working

Tags: apache2, subdomain, virtual-hosts

I have this conf-file set-up:

```
Listen 80

<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName test.example.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/django/test/test/wsgi.py
        #WSGIPythonPath /var/django/test

        <Directory /var/django/test/test>
        <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        </Files>
        </Directory>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAlias *.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Whenever I open www.example.com, test.example.com or example.com I always receive the standard apache website.

If I delete the second VirtualHost I get an access denied (since the permissions for the wsgi-file are note properly set).

But why can't I run 2 (or more) different VirtualHost of differnt subdomains?

Thanks!

Kev

PS.: I try to run a Django-Site on the subdomain test.example.com

Comment: You can, but what do you expect when boths `DocumentRoot` is the same?

Comment: In the first case I expect to have the python file executed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.

In the second  there was a "." instead of a "80".